# select a specific check box in a list view using espresso

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-espresso

I am able to select a specific check box in a list view using the position of the check box.but i want to select a check box with respect to the text next to it.
For example a list view of groceries with check boxes are present and i want to select a check box which has "tooth paste" next to it. How do we do this??

Comment: Is there any code we can review? Please go over this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to solve on my project(check the screenshot):

I've created a custom Matcher which matches a row list given the string displayed in it (i only have a row with a TextView, an ImageVIew and CheckBox).

```
    private Matcher<View> isRoleChecked() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("a whatever description");
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView view) {
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.getParent();

            CheckBox aCheck = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.myCheckbox);

            return aCheck.isChecked();
        }
    };
}
```

The magic happens in `matchesSafely(TextView view)` method where you 'catch' the layout where the checkbox exists. After that you can do whatever you want with your checkbox. You can set it to checked -> `aCheck.setChecked(true);` but that is not a good option from automation testing point of view, because you want to perform the click.
If so, you can use:

```
onView(withText("class number 0")).check(matches(isRoleChecked())).perform(click());
```

Obviously, you need to re-write the code for your needs. Hope this helps.

[image]